# Joi validation not validating required fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have 4 fields that I'm trying to validate using Joi. I want the following to be required: **Either** `first` or `second`, **And** `third` or `fourth`.

so one of the following should pass but nothing else should:

```
{first: 'yo', third: true}
// or
{second: 'bro', third: true}
// or
{first: 'yo', fourth: true}
// or
{second: 'bro', fourth: true}
```

I tried the following but it's letting `third` and `fourth` be blank.

```
function validate(data) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        first: Joi.string(),
        second: Joi.string(),
        third: Joi.boolean(),
        fourth: Joi.boolean(),
    })
        .xor('first', 'second')
        .xor('third', 'fourth');

    return schema.validate(data);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " it's letting third and fourth be blank". Like so: `{first: 'yo'}`?

Comment: Your schema seems to work just fine when testing in the sandbox: https://joi.dev/tester/

Comment: update joi module